# Makefile doesn't detect Python

Tags: shell, makefile

I've got the following in my Makefile,

```
dosomething:
    ifeq (, $(shell which python))
        $(error "Python not installed, please download and install Python to create database")
    else
        cd myfolder; python myfile.py
    endif
```

When I run `make dosomething`, it throws the error telling me to download and install python. But when I do `which python` in my shell, it says `/usr/bin/python`

Not sure what is going on here

Comment: Do the `ifeq`, `else` and `endif` lines begin with a tab character?  If so, try removing it.

Comment: Just to simplify the problem, you could try `$(info $(shell which python))`.

Comment: @G.M. That fixed it! But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the indented lines begin with a tab character?  If so then the `ifeq`, `else` and `endif` directives will be considered to be part of the command and passed to the shell for execution.

To ensure `make` evaluates those directives remove the leading tabs...

```
dosomething:
ifeq (, $(shell which python))
        $(error "Python not installed, please download and install Python to create database")
else
        cd myfolder; python myfile.py
endif
```